# Location of elements not where expected when positioning with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on an orbit simulation I have the planet orbiting, but if you look at the inner 3 planets then shift from the orbit's dashed line. On the bottom of the orbit the planet is below the line. At the top of the orbit the planet is either on or above the dashed line.

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/Pe87m/).

I think this has to do with the border width not being taken into account but everything I've tried to correct the issue hasn't worked. I'm currently using outerWidth() and outerHeight() but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```
var width = parseFloat($(this).parent().outerWidth()) / 2;
var height = parseFloat($(this).parent().outerHeight()) / 2;
var point = getPoint(width, height, angle * (Math.PI / 180));

$(this).css('left', point[0] + ($(this).parent().outerWidth() / 2) + 'px');
$(this).css('top', point[1] + ($(this).parent().outerHeight() / 2) + 'px');
```

The `getPoint` function is:

```
function getPoint(width, height, angle)
{
    var x = parseFloat(width) * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = parseFloat(height) * Math.sin(angle);
    return [x, y];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right - it's the border size.  I checked the CSS and it seemed fine, but the smaller planets were visibly off center.

To fix it, all I did was change these lines:

```
    'margin-top'  : '-' + ($(this).outerHeight() / 2) + 'px',
    'margin-left' : '-' + ($(this).outerWidth() / 2) + 'px'
```

To this (added two before dividing):

```
    'margin-top'  : '-' + (($(this).outerHeight() + 2) / 2) + 'px',
    'margin-left' : '-' + (($(this).outerWidth() + 2) / 2) + 'px'
```

You can see a working example at the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe87m/16/).

`UPDATE` - seems this isn't totally fixing the problem - as the planets round to the RHS of the orbit, they start to travel to the outer edge.  On the up side though, you know that the fix is in those two lines... you just need to compensate for the position in the right amount, which I believe may end up being dynamic or something based on planet position.

Comment: But is there a way to automate this... if the CSS changes I don't want to have to go back and update the javascript.

Comment: I don't think my fix is correct - there's a lot of factors and I think a better example for people to work with would be just one planet/orbit so that there aren't so many elements.  Yes, it could be automated, since the areas where you calculate the height/width reference parents (the circle), so you could get the border size easily.